# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Tags: python-3.x

when I'm on a previous screen and I move to this screen, and I click on close presents this error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

But when I run this screen directly, the close buttons work normally, I did some similar research but applying the resolutions I was unsuccessful, I am grateful for the help. Thanks.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import os
    
    
    def fechar():
        tela_principal.destroy()
    
    
    def tela_clientes():
        fechar()
        exec(open('cadastro_cliente.py').read(), {'c': tela_principal})
    
    
    def tela_carros():
        pass
    
    
    tela_principal = Tk()
    tela_principal.title('Principal')
    tela_principal.geometry('400x300+250+50')
    
    fr_logo = Frame(tela_principal, borderwidth=1, relief='solid')
    fr_logo.place(x=10, y=10, width=380, height=180)
    
    btn_cliente = Button(
        tela_principal, text='CADASTRO\nCLIENTE', command=tela_clientes)
    btn_cliente.place(x=30, y=220, width=100, height=50)
    
    btn_carros = Button(tela_principal, text='PESQUISA\nCARROS',
                        command=tela_carros)
    btn_carros.place(x=150, y=220, width=100, heigh=50)
    
    btn_sair = Button(tela_principal, text='SAIR', command=fechar)
    btn_sair.place(x=270, y=220, width=100, height=50)
    
    
    tela_principal.mainloop()
```

Comment: This StackOverflow site is English-only.  Please edit your question to be in English, or post it over at [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Or probably [pt.so]